# css - display div above another one

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a solution, where I have to display an error message above (z-index) a section.

The section has it css overflow attribute set to `scroll` or `hidden`. This is causing the error message to be truncate on the left side.

I would very like to keep the DOM as it is. Is there a way to display the div for the error message "above" the blue div.

[Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DavidLaberge2014/Hsw3m/2/)

**HTML :**

```
<div>
<div id="div1">
    div 1
</div>
<div id="div2">
    div 2
    <div id="msgErreur">
        Error
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS : **

```
#div1 { 
width : 48%;
border: 1px solid red;
height: 150px;
float:left;
}

#div2 { 
width : 48%;
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 150px;
float:right;
overflow-y:scroll;
 }

#msgErreur {
background:#942911;
color:white;
top:30px;
left: -10px;
width : 150px;
height : 30px;
position:relative;
z-index:5;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code in the question

Comment: `z-index: 5px` should be `z-index: 5`. but that does not solve the problem

Comment: @Alp Thanks it is fixed now ...

Comment: You could use `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` if you don't mind to count the pixels from the most left side. But i guess that's not an option.

Comment: @alp That test case is a representation of a much more complex application using templates with AngularJS. It is just to see if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

edit: 2 ways of achieving this. Relatively positioned (extra) element in an absolutely positioned one or (new) an absolutely positioned element and `transform`.

You can achieve this by using `position: absolute` on the container of the error message and an extra div relatively positioned between container and message.
The DOM is slightly modified but without moving whole blocks of code, maybe it's OK with your requirements?

Relevant **HTML**:

```
<div id="msgErreur">
    <div>Error</div>
</div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
#msgErreur {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    color: white;
}
#msgErreur > div {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px; left: -10px;
    width: 150px; height: 30px;
    background: #942911;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hsw3m/3/)**

**EDIT:** it's 2016 and **`transform: translate(X, Y)`** is compatible with a large set of browsers (IE9+ according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)).
Here's another way of achieving what OP needed, with no extra element needed:

```css
#div1 { 
    width : 48%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 150px;
    float:left;
}
#div2 { 
    width : 48%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 150px;
    float:right;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

#msgErreur {
    background:#942911;
    color:white;
    /* top:30px; */
    /* left: -10px; */
    width : 150px;
    height : 30px;
    position: absolute; /* not relative anymore */
    /* z-index:5; It's already stacked above if positioned. Needed if other positioned elements are there (a value of 1 would be enough) */
    transform: translate(-10px, 30px); /* replaces relative positioning (left and top => X and Y) */
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="div1">
        div 1
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        div 2
        <div id="msgErreur">
            Error
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/pNEKer)