# Display tooltip when container overflow is hidden

Tags: html, css

Is there a way, preferably without js, to position and display a tooltip above a container, when the container must have `overflow:hidden`, without the tooltip be affected and clipped by the container?

Here is an example to illustrate this problem:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 70px;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 96px;
  line-height: 96px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 10px #800000;
}
a.tooltips span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.7;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -76px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <a class="tooltips" href="#">Hover me for Tooltip
      <span>Tooltip</span></a>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin porttitor elit neque, in condimentum ante pulvinar et. Donec et erat nulla. Vestibulum quis porta tellus. Curabitur non blandit metus. Vestibulum nec nisi quis urna tempor pharetra. Phasellus volutpat, arcu ac malesuada porttitor, erat diam facilisis ligula, eget aliquet nibh augue.
    </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: why **must** have `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: With your current setup, I don't think that's possible. If your container is overflow hidden then you won't be able to show the tooltip child outside of the container. Whatever it is you are trying to achieve with overflow hidden, there is probably another approach to achieve what you want

Comment: @dippas because there are other stuff on the container, which must not overflow outside of it.

Comment: @AmirGonnen then show us the real content for a better assistance

Comment: @AmirGonnen put the other stuff inside of a different container inside of `.container` and make the new container overflow hidden instead. As long as your tooltip is not inside of any overflow hidden parent, you should be good

Comment: If you really need this to work without changing any structure and you know the tooltip height, then give padding bottom to overflow hidden container till the tooltip is visible. It is not a good solution as you will have empty space below the page and extra scrollbar.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There's a way to display an element in these conditions, **by having it absolutely positioned** (as a simple wrapper) and **containing a relatively positioned tooltip**.
So you need to add an element.
One important condition: the parent with `overflow: hidden` must not be positioned itself or the tooltip won't pop out/displayed above this parent.

- [Codepen](http://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/AXGaJv?editors=0100) (I renamed your `.tooltips` class as `.has-tooltip` and added 2 anothers)
- [My previous answer with a similar trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24539706/137626)

```css
 .container {
  overflow: hidden;
  /*position: relative;*/
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 70px;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
.has-tooltip {
  /*position: relative;*/
  display: inline;
}
.tooltip-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.has-tooltip:hover .tooltip-wrapper {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.7;
  /*top: 30px;*/
  /*left: 50%;*/
  /*margin-left: -76px;*/
  /* z-index: 999; defined above with value of 5 */
}

.tooltip {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
    top: 2em;
    right: 100%;
  width: 140px;
  height: 96px;
  /*margin-left: -76px;*/
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  line-height: 96px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 10px #800000;
}
.tooltip:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <a class="has-tooltip" href="#">Hover me for Tooltip
      <span class="tooltip-wrapper"><span class="tooltip">Tooltip</span></span></a>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin porttitor elit neque, in condimentum ante pulvinar et. Donec et erat nulla. Vestibulum quis porta tellus. Curabitur non blandit metus. Vestibulum nec nisi quis urna tempor pharetra. Phasellus volutpat, arcu ac malesuada porttitor, erat diam facilisis ligula, eget aliquet nibh augue.
    </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: That is interesting. I'm going to try it. Any idea what's the reason behind this behavior, that it works only when the parent is *not* positioned?

Comment: Of course not ^_^ even after asking a few very senior CSS people (edit: it isn't just stacking context or Block Formatting Context - BFC, it may be a mix of both)

Comment: A really cool implementation, however, if the tooltip container is inside a container that can be scrolled, the tooltip position will not move accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

> now i used position absolute to fixed for the tooltip, check it now

```css
.container {  
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 70px;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  z-index:9;
}
a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
a.tooltips span {
  position: fixed;
  width: 140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 96px;
  line-height: 96px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index:9999;
  top:15px;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 10px #800000;
}
a.tooltips span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.7;
  top: 40px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -76px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div  style="height:500px;">
<div class="container">
  <a class="tooltips" href="#">Hover me for Tooltip
      <span>Tooltip</span></a>
  <div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it moves with scroll , position fixed is not recommended!

Answer (score 1):

What about only changing the (div) parent's css position (via jQuery), thus making   it 'static' on mouseover ? And then back to 'relative' afterwards..

In my configuration (for multiple reason), the parent HAD TO stay both 'relative' and 'hidden'. Nothing added/changed in the css this way.

```js
$('.trigger').hover(function () {  
    $(this).closest('.parent').css({position:"static"})
    },
    function(){$(this).closest('.parent').css({position:""})
});
```

```css
.trigger {
  position: absolute;
  padding:0 15px;
  border:3px solid; 
  color:white;
  background:#838678
}

.tooltip { 
  position: absolute;
  top:90px;
  width:200px;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  background: #333;
  color: white;   
  border-radius: 9px;    
  opacity:0;
}

.trigger:hover .tooltip {  
opacity: 1;  
}

.parent { 
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
width:200px;
height:150px; 
border:4px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
    
  <div class="trigger">
    <p> hover me </p>
      
    <div class="tooltip"> 
    voilà :)
    </div>

  </div> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the easiest way to fix this adding `position:fixed` to tooltip.
However, applying fixed position will take it out of Div/container which means if you are using this in **scroll** scenario it wont work.

if you scroll and hover for tooltip. tooltip will appear at the same position & not sticky to the main element anymore.

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 70px;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
a.tooltips span {
  position: fixed;
  width: 140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 96px;
  line-height: 96px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 10px #800000;
}
a.tooltips span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.7;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -76px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <a class="tooltips" href="#">Hover me for Tooltip
      <span>Tooltip</span></a>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin porttitor elit neque, in condimentum ante pulvinar et. Donec et erat nulla. Vestibulum quis porta tellus. Curabitur non blandit metus. Vestibulum nec nisi quis urna tempor pharetra. Phasellus volutpat, arcu ac malesuada porttitor, erat diam facilisis ligula, eget aliquet nibh augue.
    </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used content-type="template" with [tooltip] and used

and 
 tag to give some space in ng-template. it will move tooltip content down (can be molded accordingly) and make it visible.

```
<a class="fas fa-question-circle" 
    [tooltip]="identifier"  content-type="template" [show-delay]="300">
 </a>
 
   <!--tool tip content wiht #identifier -->
  <ng-template #identifier>
    <p style="color: white;">
      <br>
      Quesion? Email Us!
       </p>
  </ng-template>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/69w6h.png
```