# Vue js tooltip in table after the text has been cut

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a problem making a tooltip in my vue.js document. I have tried following https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_tooltip this guide in order to make one. However this is not working for me.
I have made the following code:

EDIT: UPDATED CODE

```
<template>
<div id="app">
<div class="row">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="socialCampaignTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Client</th>
                <th scope="col">Campaign</th>
                <th scope="col">Impressions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(campaign, index) in sortedCampaignPerformance" :key="campaign.campaignID">
        <td>{{campaign.client}}</td>
        <td id="socialCampaign">
            <div class="cut">{{campaign.campaign}}</div>
            <div class="tooltip">{{campaign.campaign}}
                <span class="tooltiptext"> {{campaign.campaign}}</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          {{Intl.NumberFormat('da-DK').format(Math.round(campaign.impressions))}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
props: ['campaignPerformance'],
  methods: {
  },
  computed: {
  sortedCampaignPerformance() {
    return this.campaignPerformance.sort((a, b) => b.impressions - a.impressions)
  }
  },
created() {
 },
};
</script>

<style>
  #socialCampaignTable{
   overflow-y:scroll;
   height:350px;
    display:block;
    }
   #socialCampaign .cut {
   width :625px;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   }
   .tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
   }

   .tooltip .tooltiptext {
     visibility: hidden;
     width: 120px;
     background-color: #555;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     border-radius: 6px;
     padding: 5px 0;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     bottom: 125%;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -60px;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 0.3s;
    }

   .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }

   .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
```

I would like the tooltip to be the campaign full name, as some of the campaigns are too long to show at the table.
Can anybody help here?

Answer (score 0):

```
you haven't added styles

<style>
    table{
     overflow-y:scroll;
     height:200px;
     display:block;
     }
   td .cut {
     width :625px;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     white-space: nowrap;
     }
    .tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! However it's not working with with the given css styling, when I hover the campaigns no tooltip is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your tooltip style, that makes the tooltip appear?
Another thing that you may put the `{{campaign.campaign}}` inside the tooltipText span.

Update after updated code:
Change kind of this way the part where the tooltip is:

```html
 <tr>
  <td>Test 1</td>
  <td id="socialCampaign">
    <div class="tooltip cut">Test2
      <span class="tooltiptext"> Test 2</span>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    Test 3
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, left the styling out as it wasn't working for me. Just updated my code to how it looks now

Comment: Change then it kind of this way: 
     <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td id="socialCampaign">
            <div class="tooltip">Test2
                <span class="tooltiptext"> Test 2</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          Test 3
        </td>
      </tr>

Comment: Edited my answer above.

Comment: The class "tooltip cut" doesn't seem to work. The  table column just appear blank when using this

Comment: Alright, it won't work because of overflow: hidden. You either truncate your data in that cell if it is a string and not using overflow: hidden or try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146047/display-tooltip-when-container-overflow-is-hidden

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<div class="tooltip">
    <div class="cut">{{campaign.campaign}}</div>
    <span class="tooltiptext"> {{campaign.campaign}}</span>
</div>
```

http://tpcg.io/tXn1lslG