# Hover for tooltip doesn't work when I set overflow: hidden for its parent

Tags: html, css

I want to hide text after the first line, so that's why I've set the following:

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
```

And the whole text should be visible in the tooltip above text when you hover over it, but this doesn't work when overflow is set to hidden.

I've two similar codes here:

This stack snippet will hide text after the first line, but the tooltip will not work:

```css
.primary-text {
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/*==========TOOLTIP-TEXT POPUP==========*/

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
}

.tooltip::after {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #F2EFEF;
  border-radius: 4%;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  z-index: 999;
}

.tooltip::before {
  background-color: #F2EFEF;
  border: 1px solid #F2EFEF;
  content: ' ';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.tooltip:hover::after {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip:hover::before {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip.top::after {
  content: "Lorem ipusm sflaklghgdashgisdj fgi siodf ajifjsd josfjodjsfj";
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, calc(-100% - 10px));
}

.tooltip.top::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, calc(-100% - 5px)) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="primary-text">
  <span class="tooltip top">Lorem ipusm sflaklghgdashgisdj fgi siodfajifjsdjosfjodjsfj</span>
</div>
```

And this stack snippet will not hide text after the first line, but the tooltip will work:

```css
.primary-text {
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/*==========TOOLTIP-TEXT POPUP==========*/

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
}

.tooltip::after {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #F2EFEF;
  border-radius: 4%;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  z-index: 999;
}

.tooltip::before {
  background-color: #F2EFEF;
  border: 1px solid #F2EFEF;
  content: ' ';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.tooltip:hover::after {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip:hover::before {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip.top::after {
  content: "Lorem ipusm sflaklghgdashgisdj fgi siodf ajifjsd josfjodjsfj";
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, calc(-100% - 10px));
}

.tooltip.top::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, calc(-100% - 5px)) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="primary-text">
  <span class="tooltip top">Lorem ipusm sflaklghgdashgisdj fgi siodfajifjsdjosfjodjsfj</span>
</div>
```

The only difference beween these two fiddles is overflow:hidden. First has it, and second doesn't.

Comment: Hi, I think this answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146047/display-tooltip-when-container-overflow-is-hidden