# Absolutely positioned element with greatest z-index does not have visible overflow

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I am making a complex website with a vertically scrollable fixed position sidebar. The sidebar contains icons that display tooltips on hover. The tooltips horizontally overflow their sidebar container, and the overflow does not display.

[image: problem]

Here is the DOM structure of the sidebar and the respective z-index and positions. Note the root `<ui-view>` element is at least a sibling to all other rendering elements in the DOM.

```
<ui-view> // position: relative
    <div> // position: fixed
        <ul> // position: relative
            <ui-view> // position: relative
                <li> // position: relative
                    <a> // position: relative
                        <div> // position: absolute, tooltip here
```

All of these elements have `overflow-x: visible` and `z-index: 2000`, the highest in the DOM.

This configuration causes the tooltip overflow to be scrollable, and not visible!

Here is a working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/QVAcspXd72E4vY8D2liU?p=preview.

**UPDATE:**

The higher `div` has `overflow-y:auto` to enable vertical scrolling. Removing this makes the tooltip overflow visible, but stop the scrollbar from being vertically scrollable.

Comment: Hi, please give us a working demo with all of the relevant code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MichaelCoker Plunker posted above.

Comment: you have `overflow-y: auto;` on the `div`. That will keep the children from overflowing.

Comment: This work: https://plnkr.co/edit/AlqdNOB2oafPAqFqJqmq?p=preview ... `overflow: auto` removed

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thank you, that fixed it! The problem is now the sidebar is no longer vertically scrollable when it overflows... I want to retain vertical scrollability and have visible horizontal overflow.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Updated the plunker to demonstrate this problem.

Comment: The only way to scroll and have overflow is to make the container wide enough to accommodate the overflow, like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/ogzQrANedItyQDCoo8MP?p=preview ... or you need to put tool tips outside the sidebar and use script to move them into position when hovering an element

Comment: @LGSon You can have a positioned element _get out_ of an overflow-positioned parent and keep former where it is in the DOM: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24539706/137626

Comment: @FelipeAls Yes, technically, though as its immediate parent can't have a position, it will work similar to being outside the parent when it comes to positioning

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the angular library UI Bootstrap to get my tooltip functionality. Turns out it has a `tooltip-append-to-body` option. Set that to true and it solved all my problems!